# How to fix : ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
    import pathlib
datadir = "...My Google drive" 
datatest = pathlib.Path(datadir)   
image_count = len(list(datatest.glob('*/*.jpg')))   
print("จำนวนรูป : ",image_count)

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  datatest,
  validation_split=0.1,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(IMG_ROWS, IMG_COLS),
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  datatest,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(IMG_ROWS, IMG_COLS),
  batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_ds
```

---

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_ds

------------------------------- code error --------------------------------

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-0219205d9ccf> in <module>()
----> 1 (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_ds

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: What is the value of `train_ds`?

Comment: train_ds returns one tuple containing (images, labels). You are trying to assign the result to two tuples. Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory, this function returns a tuple of 2 items, (images, labels). Here you assign the output to 2 tuples (4 values), so the error is telling you that there are too many values, and the output generated cannot be "unpacked" (don't have enough values) to assign to each of them. You should only do

```
(x_train, y_train) = train_ds
```

Hope this help fix it!